# How to view/execute granted stored procedure in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The user that I use to access a particular DB has been granted EXECUTE privilege for a stored procedure managed by another user. Is there any way to view or run that stored procedure in Oracle SQL developer like a regular stored procedure? At the moment I don't see it in the Procedure tab in connections to right click and run. I am executing the stored procedure in java but I need to be able to test it in SQL developer.

Comment: yes you can, if you know what the "original" schema name is. Just type schemaowner.procedurename

Comment: @OracleDev: Cheers. I suppose I was hoping that it would update my list of stored procedures. Stored proc has IN and OUTs and using the run function in SQL developer is easier.

Comment: check Alex Poole's answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure won't appear in the tree list immediately under your connection, as those are only ever the ones that the user you are connected as owns themselves. (If you right-click and choose 'Filter', there is an option to 'override schema filter', but even with a filter and that flag set you don't see other users' procedures.)

But right at the bottom of the list of objects types under your connection is an 'Other Users' entry. If you expand that, find the owner of the procedure and expand that, and then expand the list of procedures under *that* user - you'll see all of *their* procedures that you have permission to view/execute.

You can then run it from there the same way you would run your own procedures.

You can also right-click on your connection and choose 'Schema Browser'; then in the tab that appears you can more easily change user, and change the object type to 'Procedures'. You might find that faster than navigating the tree.

@thatjeffsmith has [a post about navigating via the tree or the dropdowns](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/02/sql-developer-trick-dropdown-vs-tree/) (of course - should have looked their first...)

Comment: Cheers, the stored proc in grantor has been updated and this is not being reflected in the 'Other users' stored proc which is the old version I am assuming. What needs to be done to cascade the changes through?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, you should always be seeing the current code. If you opened the procedure in your session, and then it was updated, you might just need to close and re-open it. Or you can right-click and refresh the list.

Comment: No it's not updating to the new version. A comment at start of proc contains details of updates so it's easy to track changes. Do you know any reason for changes down being reflected? This is why the java code was breaking as old version has more IN parameters than the new version

Comment: Are you sure the updated version has actually been compiled; and is in the schema (and database) you expect? If a Java call is hitting the old version too then that is what actually exists in the DB/schema it's using. You can query `all_objects` to see the `last_ddl_time`, and `all_source` to see the current code; but that's what SQL Developer is looking at too.

Comment: check the Info page and LAST_DDL_TIME for your procedure - btw, we don't cache that page, we're showing you what the database has for the procedure source. you can open the view - log - statements panel and SEE the sql we use to populate the code editor for yourself

Comment: I found the problem. Connection details provided for grantor by another team were for the wrong environment, dev instead of SIT. Should have checked SID with more care. Thanks for guidance

Comment: @FrancisDrumm i was gonna say make sure you're in the right database :) But glad to see you got it going. Let us know if you need any help getting going otherwise with pl/sql in sql developer - you can find my online in various places pretty easily

Answer (score 0):

If you have a procedure "test_procedure" in your shema you would execute it like this:

```
begin
  test_procedure;
end;
```

If you have it in another schema, lets say "parent" then you would call it like this:

```
begin
  parent.test_procedure;
end;
```